# Is it possible to specify a custom alphanumeric sender id to Twilio Verify Service? Overriding the default of AUTHMSG

Tags: twilio, sms, verify

Twilio allows you to setup a custom alphanumeric sender id for SMS messages sent by it. The Verify service sends a SMS with an OTP. I would like to change the alphanumeric sender id of this message from AUTHMSG to something custom like MYCOMPANYNAME.

This [page](https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360009533114-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Verify-and-Authy) hints that there might be a possibility by saying.

We use generic Alphanumeric Senders (AUTHMSG, TWVerify, and VerifyTWL) by default for Verify and Authy API messages in 79 countries around the world. When One-time Password (OTP) messages are sent via Verify or Authy in one of these supported countries, **and a specific sender hasn't been configured**

But i couldnt find anywhere in the documentation anything pointing to it + This page seems to talk mostly about Authy which i know is being deprecated.

I expected there be a way to setup an alphanumeric sender id for the SMS channel, but that doenst seem to be the case.